# How can I check one list against another to see if the second list contains any elements from the first list?

Tags: list, haskell

Given two lists `xs` and `ys` is there a way to check if any or all (but nothing else) of the values in `xs` is in `ys` ?

Answer (score 2):

If there are no repetitions in `xs` you can do it like that:

```
null (xy \\ ys)
```

You have to `import Data.List` for the `\\` operator.

Comment: No there are no repetitions. Here ys is a larger list which elements is of a specific type. And xs is a small list with all the different types. So i have a function that returns true if the values in ys is not different from any of the values in xs.